# Use count() in relational algebra

Tags: database-theory, relational-algebra

> Person(name, phone)
>   Mike 456-789
>   Mike 123-456
>   John 230-785
>   $\dots \dots$

How to get those people who have more than one phone numbers with relational algebra? This sounds simple, but I am frustrated with all materials that I've learned.

Is it correct syntax to use count() like $\pi_{name}(\sigma_{count(phone)>2}(Person))$ ?

Answer (score 9):

A syntax of **aggregate operation** in relational-algebra (according to [1]) is as follows :

> $G_1,G_2,...,G_n \hspace{2 mm}\textbf{g}\hspace{2 mm}
>   F_1(A_1),F_2(A_2),...,F_m(A_m)(E)$
>
> where $E$ is any relational-algebra expression; $G_1,G_2,...,G_n$
>   constitute a list of attributes on which to group; each $F_i$ is an
>   aggregate function; and each $A_i$ is an attribute name.

Thus your query would look like :
$\pi_{name}(\sigma_{phone>1}(name\hspace{2 mm}\textbf{g}\hspace{2 mm} count (phone)( Person)\hspace{2 mm}))$

[1] A. Silberschatz, H. Korth, S. Sudarshan, Database System Concepts, 5th Edition