# Using count() in Relational Algebra

Tags: database-theory, relational-algebra

*Sell (Bar, Beer)*

I want a table in which the first column has the name of the beer and the second has the total number of bars which sell that beer, but I have no idea how to use count () in the right way to obtain this.

Could it be *Beer G count(Bar) as count_bar (Sell)* ?

And later that, how could I set a table with the best-selling beer (or the best-selling beers)?

Comment: How is your algebra's count defined? If you suspect that use, why, & what are you sure & unsure about? How is this like or not like some similar example you can quote & understand? Otherwise you are just asking us to rewrite the documentation with no idea where or why you are stuck. Quote the documentation for your algebra's count. PS There are many RAs (relational algebras). They differ in operators & even what a relation is. Give operator definitions & your reference for yours. Eg textbook name, edition & page. PS Please ask 1 question per post. [ask] [help]

Comment: I think I was very clear about what I want to do. Just by the name of the *count* operator you can understand its functionality a little bit. I would like to understand how that value is returned and how I could write the result of what I want using this operator, which counts how many times some value appears. As a matter of fact, as there were two simple questions, I thought it would be okay to ask both. @philipxy

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use count() in relational algebra](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/29897/use-count-in-relational-algebra)

Comment: Your comment doesn't counter anything in mine. PS Especially "There are many RAs". (There is among RAs at least one aggregation operator called G. We don't know if it's yours. Or if it's even in your RA. And it isn't a count operator per se, although it can count. But you should know that from the definition you have been given.) PS Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: This would be easier to answer for (standard) SQL, if off-topic.

Comment: Hi @Joe. Relational-algebra (RA) has no count() operator. RA operates over relations. That is, given some relations, its operations (union, set-diff, cartesian-product, select, project...) brings some other relations. Counting is an aggregation function that, given a relation, returns you a number. This is why count() is not in RA.

However, as another comment suggest, counting is possible in SQL. Is it the case that you want to know how to do it in SQL? If this is the case, we would need to know the SQL schema (the tables you have) for helping you building the queries.

Comment: @441Juggler Aggregation wasn't part of the original basic RAs. But aggregation & other operators extending basic RAs have been developed for use with those operators. (Eg The G I mentioned.) The combinations are called RAs. Also "algebra" doesn't mean anything in particular & RA operator arguments have never been limited to relations. Also one could define operators that only input & output relations that cannot be expressed using basic RA. So your "arguments must be relations" is not a sound "why" aggregation can't be considered a RA operator. "There are many RAs".